# Delete message from Azure Storage Queue using REST API

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to simply Get a message off an Azure Storage Queue and then delete it using the REST API.
I can retrieve the message and get a popreceipt but when I try and use this to delete the message, I keep getting, "The specified message does not exist."

In the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-message2) it looks like you only have to supply the popreceipt however further down the page, it says,

> After a client retrieves a message with the Get Messages operation, the client is expected to process and delete the message. To delete the message, you must have two items of data returned in the response body of the Get Messages operation:

> 1. The message ID, an opaque GUID value that identifies the message in
>    the queue.

> 2. A valid pop receipt, an opaque value that indicates that the message has been retrieved.

So this implies you do need to send the MessageId as well but there is nothing in the docs that specifies where to place the messageid.

The URI in the docs says to pass DELETE to
https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages/messageid?popreceipt=string-value and I have tried replacing messageid with the actual messageid from the GET but this does not seem to be correct.

Has anyone used this and can explain why I always get "The specified message does not exist"  when trying to DELETE the message off the queue or am I missing something?

Comment: You would get this error if the message was dequeued again making the popreceipt value invalid. Please check if that’s not the case.

Comment: I don't believe anything else is reading off the queue - when I am reading the message, I am setting the visibility timeout to 2 minutes so theoretically, nothing else can read that message? Also, if I use the Azure Nuget library, this requires you to pass MessageId and PopReceipt so am I right in the REST API, you only need PopReceipt?

Answer (score 0):

- When  GET message /dequeue a message is requested, the message becomes
  invisible for certain amount of time .In this mean time ,if it is
  not deleted in  process which dequeued ,it will be visible again as
  said by @gaurav mantri and have a chance to be  picked up by another
  process i.e ; ***`when you perform  get message  operation with a visibility timeout reached, another message object is returned with a new pop_receipt .`***
- So please check the time, when you dequeue the message and wait if
  the time is out or delete it on time as sometimes  encoding process
  may take more time than the message invisibility timeout.
- Also please note that the maximum timeout interval for Queue service
  operations is 30 seconds. If the server timeout interval elapses
  before the service has finished processing the request, the service
  returns an error.
- For the next process pop receipt is updated and so using old one
  gives error error code 404 (Not Found) because message with a
  matching pop receipt wont be found .
- `So please check by gradually  increasing  the invisibility timeout.`

**References:**

1. [Queue getmessage fails - some messages only. (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad75ba0f-c1e6-4206-a1e4-b74d5b309acb/queue-getmessage-fails-some-messages-only?forum=windowsazuredata)
2. [Setting timeouts for Queue service operations (REST API) - Azure
   Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-timeouts-for-queue-service-operations)